# Finding values to make vectors linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

For which real values of $\lambda$ do the following vectors form a linearly dependent set in $R^3$?

$v_1 = \langle \lambda, -1/2, -1/2 \rangle$,$v_2 = \langle -1/2, \lambda, -1/2 \rangle$,$v_3 = \langle -1/2, -1/2, \lambda \rangle$

Could I simply put $v_1,v_2,v_3$ into a 3 by 3 matrix and find the determinant such that it is equal to 0?

Comment: making lambda equal to -1/2 will definitely make the set linearly dependent because all 3 vectors will be the same

Comment: Are you asking for a linearly dependent or linearly independent. In the title it says you want linearly independent but in the question you say you want linearly dependent set.

Comment: But in general, computing the determinant works (of course, then you have to factor a cubic equation...).

Comment: If this an exercise out of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, then the determinant should be ignored as a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is exactly right.

Let 
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
\lambda & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2} & \lambda & -\frac{1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \lambda
\end{array}\right]
$$
Then
$$
\det A
=\frac{1}{4} \, {\left(4 \, \lambda^{2} - 1\right)} \lambda - \frac{1}{2} \, \lambda - \frac{1}{4}
=\frac{1}{4} \, {\left(2 \, \lambda + 1\right)}^{2} {\left(\lambda - 1\right)}
$$
This proves that your vectors are linearly independent if and only if $\lambda\neq-1/2$ and $\lambda\neq 1$.